# Docker image SHA of layer inside my image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-registry

I build my docker image with the Dockerfile

```
FROM gcr.io/distroless/java
ENV JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=96"
ARG JAR_FILE
ADD target/${JAR_FILE} /app/main.jar
WORKDIR /app
CMD ["main.jar"]
```

After the image be build I need to know the SHA of `gcr.io/distroless/java` inside my image

Comment: What will you do with it once you have it?  Do you need the image ID from `docker images`, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need to have SHA of the parent image inside your image.
If you are concerned from security perspective then you can have a look at 'DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST' which makes sure that only official signed images get pulled.